# PHP UBBCode forms

Tags: php, str-replace

I want the user to be able to create their own form. They have a editor which they can put their code in to have the form appear on their website.

[image]

That's my database, however it does not work the way I want it to work. My code is like this:

```
$ubb = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM ubb');
$ubb->execute();
$ubbresult = $ubb->get_result();
while ($row = $ubbresult->fetch_assoc()) {
    function ubbreplace($text){
        $text = str_replace($row["trig"],$row["html"],$text);
        return $text;
    }
}
```

and somewhere down the website, it will output the function:

```
<?php echo ubbreplace($row["content"]); ?>
```

I'm getting undefined errors. That may be because I don't have the `ubbreplace` function in the `while`, and I've tried to put it in the `while` but I'm still getting the error.

> Notice: Undefined variable: row in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\projecten\test\index.php on line 74

Not sure what is going wrong anymore. I've tried everything I came up with but that all doesn't work.